# Z-Index and Positioning: Items keep pushing down upon use of 'Particleground' Jquery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am kind of confused about z-index and positioning. I have read questions and articles about this, and I have been struggling.

I am trying to use a a Jquery Plugin: 'Particleground': https://github.com/jnicol/particleground/find/master

I have used the plugin and I am getting the particles on the top of the page. But my entire header page has been pushed down, but I want it to appear on top. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Make the particles container:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
z-index: 0;
```

and your content container:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
/* dont touch the height, it will adapt to the content */
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! But now I am having trouble with the 'position: absolute' on the content container....the contents all seem to follow the scroll down.

Comment: Also, does anyone know how to 'stop' (or cover) the particleground on certain parts of the webpage? :)